# How to get row from SQL database with a String

Tags: java, android

So in the app I am developing the user can types in a string and selects an address. When they select done the address is put into a geofence and when they enter that geofence a notification is posted. The problem I am having is when I try to add the strings of a row from that name on notification press. The names are the same yet the cursor can not find the row with the string. Thanks in advance!

Here is the error:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.ManagerDatabaseAdapter.getDataArray(ManagerDatabaseAdapter.java:64)
        at com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.getAppToOpen(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:35)
        at com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.sendNotification(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:82)
        at com.nick.mowen.receiptmanager.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.onHandleIntent(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java:64)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is the method to get the String[] of values:

```
public String[] getDataArray(String name) {
        String[] columns = {ManagerHelper.NAME,ManagerHelper.CODE,ManagerHelper.ADDRESS};
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ManagerHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, ManagerHelper.NAME + " = '" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);
        String[] data = new String[3];
        data[0] = cursor.getString(1);
        data[1] = cursor.getString(2);
        data[2] = cursor.getString(3);
        return data;
    }
```

Here is the code to add the notification and get details:

```
public String[] getAppToOpen(String names) {
        managerDatabaseAdapter = new ManagerDatabaseAdapter(this);
        selectArgs = managerDatabaseAdapter.getDataArray(names);
        return selectArgs;
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = "There is hopefully no error";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            //Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(int geofenceTransition, List triggeringGeofences) {
        String[] split = {":", " "};
        String name = triggeringGeofences.get(0).toString();
        newSplit = name.split(split[0]);
        secondSplit = newSplit[1].split(split[1]);
        return secondSplit[0];
    }

    private void sendNotification(String geofenceTransitionDetails) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Receipt Code Reminder").setContentText(geofenceTransitionDetails).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_maps_local_restaurant).setTicker("Receipt Code Reminder").setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, ViewCodeActivity.class);
        localIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, getAppToOpen(geofenceTransitionDetails));
        TaskStackBuilder localTaskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        localTaskStackBuilder.addParentStack(ViewCodeActivity.class);
        localTaskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(localIntent);
        builder.setContentIntent(localTaskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        ((NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(this.mID, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: *<shivers>* Yet another program just asking for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Which is line 64? I'm guessing.... `getString(3)`, since `getString()` uses zero-based indexing.

Comment: In your query you need to pass the parameters in the arguments section. In your method to return the string [] of values, within your query, give this a try: ___ ManagerHelper.NAME + " = ?", new String [] {name}, null _____

Comment: Looks like you're giving a hacker a big smile buddy.

Comment: Why is it so easy to hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Index -1 requested" indicates that you are querying a Cursor without first calling `cursor.moveToFirst()`. Also, it is highly recommended that you use constants with semantic names for your columns, rather than 1, 2 and 3.